# Regex remove all lines after specific line notepad++

Tags: command-line, notepad++, regex

I am selecting specific line and I want it to be removed with all the text and lines after it.

Code I use to select the line containing needed string:

```
^.*(string).*$
```

Also I another one to remove it and text before it for another string.

It would be great if I could replace all the text and lines with a one custom line.

I've tried adding .* and \r\n, but nothing is working..

Comment: It would even be great to simply remove/replace all after specific characters like "?>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It was simple as hell.

This simple line did what I wanted, maybe it will help for someone else too.

```
(\string).*$
```

It will select everything after string including the string

Comment: Please describe where do you write (\string).*$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question this script answers the first problem.  For the second problem use nearly the same script and run diff on the two files.

```
#!/bin/bash -
#
gawk '
# /pattern/ { action } 
BEGIN { flag = 0 }
/^.*foo.*$/ { flag++ }
{
if (flag == 0)
    print $0 
}
' file
```

Comment: how can I use this on notepad++?

Comment: "If I understand your question" You didn't. OP is using Windows and Notepad++ **not** bash.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the line. Ctrl-G.
Ctrl-H for search and replace.
Enter .*$ in "Find".  Blank in "Replace with"
Select Regular Expression and check ".matches newlines"
Hit Replace